# Can += change the mutable list by adding a string?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of strings and want to add another string to each of the strings in the list. I thought the string is mutable, but the result shows the opposite. Here is my example:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
for v in a :
    v += "x"
assert a == ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
```

If the list of strings is mutable, why is the "x" not being added to each element in a (["abcx", "defx", "ghix"])?

Comment: the list is mutable, but the strings aren't.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Fabre Thanks for the hint. so why is list comprehensive applied on the string, the string can be changed?

Comment: the string cannot be changed, but you can toss away the old version of your list and get a new one with the contents you want

Answer (score 2):

the list is mutable but the strings inside it aren't. So when you do:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
for v in a :
    v += "x"
```

despite the `+=` operator, since strings are immutable, the reference of `v` changes (and the value with x appended is lost).

you could do:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += "x"
```

but looping on the indexes that's very unpythonic. Interesting only when you need to modify a few values ("random" access by index). Works "in-place" for the `a` list.

You could rebuild the list using list comprehension, that would the most pythonic way (would *replace* `a`, instead of modifying it):

```
a = [i+"x" for i in a]
```

Comment: Doing what's simple and obvious is pythonic. Rebuilding an entire list when you only need to mutate one element -- that's just silly.

Comment: note that all elements are mutated here, not only one. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: Fair enough. I've perhaps become too sensitive to the gratuitous use of list comprehensions on this site.

Comment: random write access doesn't need list comps, that's true.

Comment: Your list comprehension doesn't quite do the same thing as the `for` loop. If there's another reference to `a`, then the `for` loop will modify it while the comprehension will not. The comprehension doesn't mutate the list, it replaces it.